# PHPExcel formula COUNTIFS from other sheet

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am working on a very large sheet, that sheet is created from database and have 40 columns with more than 3000 rows, I set its title `Backup Data` in Php Excel

Now I have created a new sheet where I can set value of different cells. I need to use countifs formula to show results from `Backup Data` sheet to `Summary` Sheet

```
$sheetSummary->setCellValue('E39', '=COUNTIFS(\'Backup Data\'!$H:$H,"=KTM", \'Backup Data\'!$J:$J,"=Full Size", \'Backup Data\'!$Y:$Y,"<>SPD", \'Backup Data\'!$U:$U, ">=1-Dec-12", \'Backup Data\'!$U:$U, "<=31-Dec-12")');
```

When I use a formula in php

A file is prompted but when I open the file in notepad it is having this text http://pastie.org/5584430

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the use of column references such as $H:$H and $J:$J aren't yet supported in formulae by PHPExcel. use ranges instead (such as $H1:$H3000) or disable precalculation on save

**EDIT**

To disable precalculation on save:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(FALSE);
$objWriter->save('myFile.xlsx');
```

Comment: Thank you Mark for a prompt response. I really appreciate your help last time. I have changed the formula as per your suggestion to ranges, but it still gave the same errors. Can you please let me know how to disable prealculaiton on save?

Comment: It worked, So I assumed that setting precalculateformulas to false will store the value as STRING and when opened in excel it is calculated and if it is true, PHPExcel tries to calculate the value.

Comment: It stores only the formula: forcing MS Excel to recalculate when the file is opened. The default behaviour is to store both the formula and the calculated value, so MS Excel doesn't need to recalculate on opening the file

Comment: @MarkBaker Do you know why it still throws an error for my formula even after setting the precalculation to `false`?